# Generic array as parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make the following function which counts the number of distinct elements in any array:

```
public static long distinctElements(T[] ar)
{
    return Arrays.asList(ar).stream().distinct().count();
}
```

The problem here is that I cannot use 'T[] ar' as a parameter (Java says it doesn't know the type T). How can I fix this? This function is in a utility class which does not incorporate the type T (like ArrayList and TreeSet do).

Answer (score 4):

```
public static <T> long distinctElements(T[] ar)
```

Should do the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not know what `T` is. It would also be a legal name for a class, for example. Therefore, you first have to define that `T` is a type variable.

You do that by placing it in angles before the return type as follows:

```
public static <T> long distinctElements(T[] ar) { ... }
```

Note also that you do not need generics in your case. If `A` is a subtype of `B`, then `A[]` is also a subtype of `B[]` (this is *not* the case for generics, by the way). So you can also define your method as follows:

```
public static long distinctElements(Object[] ar) { ... }
```

an be able to call it with exactly the same arrays as argument.

Answer (score 1):

`T` is not declared, so the compiler is complaining about that. Declare it at method class:

```
public static <T> long distinctElements(T[] ar) {
    return Arrays.asList(ar).stream().distinct().count();
}
```

Also, you could ease the creation of a list by using `Arrays#stream`:

```
public static <T> long distinctElements(T[] ar) {
    return Arrays.stream(ar).distinct().count();
}
```